# How do I pass args while debugging a node.js project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-2017

*Please note this is specifically for VS2017. Everything I've turned up while searching is for VS Code.*

I can pass args just fine running a node.js project from CMD. But in VS2017 the args I placed in the project properties page's **Script arguments** field aren't getting passed to the script. I've tried with and without quotes.

[image: screenshot of properties page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating VS 2017 to the latest release (Version 15.2 (26430.16) as of this writing) fixed the issue.

Comment: If so, this issue has been fixed by the latest update, since it has been resolved, you could mark your solution as the answer. Have a nice day:)